# jQuery UI autocomplete works only one time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI for an autocomplete field, however since I changed my php file in order for it to use JSON encoding, the autocomplete only works the first time (on page load). The error I get in the console after this first time is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

Code:

```
$project.autocomplete({
minLength: 2,
source: 'includes/search.php',
open: function (result) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').off('menufocus hover mouseover');
        }
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $project.val(ui.item.label);
    showResultsTitle(ui.item.title);
    return false;
},
focus: function( event, ui ) {
  $project.val( ui.item.label);
  return false;

}
```

});

I know that more people have this issue, but the proposed solutions all did not work for me.

Comment: Use some different method for source property.. else first use an ajax for getting source response and use that result data in auto complete source by keeping that data in global

Comment: Thanks! But are you sure? Since it has always worked before we changed it to JSON.

Comment: It may work.. but am not sure in your case :)

Comment: We have a working version here: www.filmmate.io, so it is really strange that the exact same code is not working on a different website..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the jQuery was also included in a second php file, instead of only in the home (HTML) page. After removing this, the autocomplete also worked after the first time.